# How to filter anything but numbers from a string

Tags: vb.net

I want to filter out other characters from a string as well as split the remaining numbers with periods.

This is my string: `major.number=9minor.number=10revision.number=0build.number=804`

and this is the expected output: `9.10.0.804`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the text you are wanting to remove consistant as in always the same?

Comment: it will always be in this format but the numbers may change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to my comment, if your text is going to be constant you can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) to remove the text and [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) to add your deliminators.  Quick example using your string.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim value As String = "major.number=9minor.number=10revision.number=0build.number=804"
    Dim seperator() As String = {"major.number=", "minor.number=", "revision.number=", "build.number="}

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(".", value.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string does not always follow a specific pattern, you could use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim value as String = "major.number=9minor.number=10revision.number=0build.number=804"

    Dim version as String = Regex.Replace(value, "\D*(\d+)\D*", "$1.") ' Run the regex
    version = version.Substring(0, version.Length - 1) ' Trim the last dot
End
```

Note you should `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`.